# webview in CoordinatorLayout won't scroll after upgrading to design to 23

Tags: android, webview, android-coordinatorlayout

Everything worked fine with com.android.support.design:22.2.1 and now with 23.2.1 webview won't scroll

Activity's layout looks like the following

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout >
      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />

      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

  <!-- The navigation drawer -->
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and fragment that will be inserted(?) into pager looks like the following. (simplified)
I tried adding NestedScrollView as a parent of webview but it won't change the result.

```
<RelativeLayout >
  // <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView >
  <WebView />
  // </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```